# Fastest way to check if a column has more than N unique values?

Tags: r, data.table

It is very straightforward to use `length(unique(x))`/ `dplyr::n_distinct(x)`/`data.table::uniqueN(x)` to get the exact number of unique values of a vector, but that is quite a lot of overhead if I have a table with millions of rows and I just want to check which columns have more than, let's say, 5 distinct values.

I considered sampling the vector, or looping through the vector and stopping early if the count reaches N, but on both approaches I feel it's quite easy to get unlucky.

Is there a better approach?

Sidenote: this is to be done on a large data.table (that may not have those columns set as keys), so any special data.table trickery would be welcome. My current approach is this:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
data <- data.table(x = rpois(n = 1e6, lambda = 100),
                   y = rpois(n = 1e6, lambda = 1),
                   z = 'A')

setkeyv(data, c('x','y','z'))
data[, lapply(.SD, function(x) uniqueN(x) > 5)]
```

Comment: Perhaps, `nlevels(as.factor(x))`

Comment: please share your exact query for data.table, you may be missing opportunities for optimization that we can't tell if we don't know what you tried

Comment: Is there a way to know how data.table has indexed the keyed column? I would be enough to know the first and las index. Is that what uniqueN does?

Comment: @MichaelChirico updated with my current approach. Thanks

Comment: if the count is not done by group, you're better off running lapply(data, uniqueN) to skip the overhead of [ (probably won't make a huge difference). you might also try to setkey to the column with highest cardinality, and run setindex for the other individual columns. unique may run faster then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a set of very fast functions in the 'collapse' package.  I'm not sure how much of a speed-up you'd get, but the last line of your code could be changed to

```
data[, lapply(.SD, function(x) fNdistinct(x) > 5)]
```

Comment: `fNdistinct` has a  `data.frame` method, so `fNdistinct(data) > 5` would also work.